# Store information using session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm new to ASP.NET :) and I'd like to understand more about `session`. Here's a simple example: Every time I click the button it will add one more integer to `listInt` and I store the list using `Session["listInt"]`.

```
public partial class TestSession : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["listInt"] == null)
            {
                Session["listInt"] = new List<Int16>();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void AddInt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int16 i = 0;
        List<Int16> listInt = (List<Int16>)Session["listInt"];
        listInt.Add(i);
        Session["listInt"] = listInt;
        Response.Write("Hello!");

    }
}
```

Here's the thing I don't understand, if I comment the line `Session["listInt"] = listInt;`, whenever I click the variable `Session["listInt"]` still store the value (means still add more integer to the list):

```
        Int16 i = 0;
        List<Int16> listInt = (List<Int16>)Session["listInt"];
        listInt.Add(i);
        //Session["listInt"] = listInt;  //No idea why....
        Response.Write("Hello!");
```

Can anyone please tell me how session works in this case? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list is a reference type,  so when you retrieve it from the server via the session state container you actually get a reference to some object in the server memory.  Hence no need to reassign it later.